# What is ShearX and ShearY and how do you get the angle of the AffineTransform from it?

Tags: java

I have looked at several questions on the internetzzz about this however none of them are straight forward and answer the question.

---

If this is a bad question or is completely wrong somehow may you please explain to me why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a very, very casual answer - mathematicians would cringe in horror - but here goes: Take a square.  Smear it horizontally to create a parallelogram.  You have just shearX'ed it.  If you apply a shearY transform and a shearX transform, you'll convert your square to a diamond.

Angular rotation is completely different.  That has to do with rotating the shape.

I think the reason you aren't getting any answers is that your question assumes that shear and rotation are somehow interconnected, which isn't the case.  You can't compute rotation from shear.

Affine Transforms allow 3 transoformations: Translation, rotation, shear.  Those are orthogonal.